# How to get email (having '+') from URL in Parameters in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encodeuricomponent

When I hit the page `/login?email=abc+dev@xyz.com`
In Ruby's Controller,
The Parameters are: `{"email"=>"abc dev@xyz.com"}`

`+` is missing in this parmas.
What is the correct way to get email in parameters ?
encode URI will give me same(that is, `URI::encode("abc+dev@xyz.com")` is equals to `"abc+dev@xyz.com"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Rack::Utils.escape()`

```
Rack::Utils.escape("abc+dev@xyz.com")
# => "abc%2Bdev%40xyz.com"
```

Or with Javascript you can use `encodeURIComponent()`

```
encodeURIComponent("abc+dev@xyz.com")
"abc%2Bdev%40xyz.com"
```

Comment: javascript encodeURIComponent() solves my problem. Thanks :)